# Where to put business logic in django

Tags: django, django-models, transactions, django-admin, business-logic

For example,  Account 1--> *User --> 1 Authentication 
*1 account has multiple users and each user will have 1 authentication*

I come from java background so what I usually do is

1. define these classes as java beans (ie, just getter and setter, no logic attached)
2. create AccountManager ejb class, define create_account method (with takes 1 account, list of users)
3. preparing data in the web layer, then pass data into AccountManager ejb, for instance:
   `accountManager.createAccount(account, userList)`

But in django, the framework advocates that you put domain logic into model classes (row level) or associated manager classes (table level), which makes things bit awkward. Yes, it is fine that if your logic is only involves one table, but in the real application, usually each step will involve multiple different tables or even databases, so what should I do in this case?

Put the logic into View? I don't think this is good practice at all. or even overwrite the save method in model class, passing in extra data by using **kwargs? then the backend will break.

I hope this illustrates my confusion with where business logic should be placed in a django application.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if you've read the section on [Managers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/) in Django, it seems to solve your current situation.  Assuming you have the following `Account` model defined, `User` is built-in.

```
# accounts/models.py

class AccountManager(models.Manager):
    def create_account(self, account, user_list):
        ...

class Account(models.Model):
    objects = AccountManager()
```

Feel free to separate your manager code in a separate file if it gets too big.  In your views:

```
# views.py

from accounts.models import Account

Account.objects.create_account(account, user_list)
```

The business logic is still in the models.

**EDIT**

The keyword here is override, not overwrite. If you override the model's save method, you have to keep in mind that any create, update operations from within your web app and admin will use this new functionality.  If you only want those business logic to happen once in a specific view, it might be best to keep it out of `save`.

I guess you can put your business logic in its own regular class.  You will have to instantiate that class each time you need to run your business logic.  Alternatively, you can put your business logic as a static function in this new class if you want to skip the OOP approach.

Comment: Hi Thierry, do you think overwrite save method is good idea?

Also. isn't manager object should be more focused on table level logic? (just curious, as now I am pretty convinced with your approach)

Answer (score 3):

What I'm doing is that most of my apps have `service.py` file with business logic. This is because if I need a function that works with models from multiple apps I simply cannot do this:

```
# shop/models.py
from auth.models import User, Team
```

This code will be stuck in circular reference loop.

But I'm gonna move most likely from `service.py` to app with structure like this:

```
service/
    auth.py
    customers.py
    another_set_of_functions.py
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the example that you illustrated above with the accountManager.createAccount(account, userList) seems like something that could be easily done my adding a createAccount method to the account model. If you feel the need to take business logic outside of the model though you could always just create a new module that host your business logic, and then import and used in in your views.